# Haskell Stack install of ghc-mod fails at old time and clock

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, ghc-mod

Installing ghc-mod through stack fails. I've tried all the solutions I found googleing to no avail. I've installed happy and alex. All the other solutions I've found are 1-2 years old and relate to upgrading to GHC 8.

> ### ERROR OUTPUT
>
> stack install ghc-mod
>
> clock-0.7.2: configure
>
> clock-0.7.2: build
>
> old-time-1.1.0.3: configure
>
> ### OLDTIME LOG
>
> ```
> --  While building custom Setup.hs for package old-time-1.1.0.3 using:   
>
> /tmp/stack23769/old-time-1.1.0.3/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0 configure --with-ghc=/home/ian/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/bin/ghc --with-ghc-pkg=/home/ian/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/bin/ghc-pkg --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=/home/ian/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.18/8.0.2/pkgdb --libdir=/home/ian/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.18/8.0.2/lib --bindir=/home/ian/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.18/8.0.2/bin --datadir=/home/ian/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.18/8.0.2/share --libexecdir=/home/ian/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.18/8.0.2/libexec --sysconfdir=/home/ian/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.18/8.0.2/etc --docdir=/home/ian/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.18/8.0.2/doc/old-time-1.1.0.3 --htmldir=/home/ian/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.18/8.0.2/doc/old-time-1.1.0.3 --haddockdir=/home/ian/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/lts-9.18/8.0.2/doc/old-time-1.1.0.3 --dependency=base=base-4.9.1.0 --dependency=old-locale=old-locale-1.0.0.7-KGBP1BSKxH5GCm0LnZP04j
> Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
> Logs have been written to: /home/ian/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/old-time-1.1.0.3.log
>
>
> [1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/stack23769/old-time-1.1.0.3/Setup.hs, /tmp/stack23769/old-time-1.1.0.3/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/Main.o )
> [2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /home/ian/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /tmp/stack23769/old-time-1.1.0.3/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/StackSetupShim.o )
> Linking /tmp/stack23769/old-time-1.1.0.3/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup ...
> Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
> configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler     checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
> checking whether the C compiler works... yes
> checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
> checking for suffix of executables...
> checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/tmp/stack23769/old-time-1.1.0.3':
> configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
> If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
> See `config.log' for more details
> ```
>
> ### Clock Log
>
> ```
> --  While building custom Setup.hs for package clock-0.7.2 using:
>   /home/ian/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
>
> Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
>
> Logs have been written to: /home/ian/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/clock-0.7.2.log
>
> Configuring clock-0.7.2...
> Building clock-0.7.2...
> Preprocessing library clock-0.7.2...
> /tmp/stack23769/clock-0.7.2/Clock.hsc:44:0: warning: "hsc_alignment" redefined
> /tmp/stack23769/clock-0.7.2/In file included from .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/System/Clock_hsc_make.c:1:0:
> /home/ian/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/template-hsc.h:88:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
>  #define hsc_alignment(t...) \
>
> /usr/bin/ld: .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/System/Clock_hsc_make.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
> /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/System/Clock_hsc_make.o failed (exit code 1)
> command was: /usr/bin/gcc .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/System/Clock_hsc_make.o .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/System/Clock_hsc_utils.o -o .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6-nopie/Cabal-1.24.2.0/build/System/Clock_hsc_make -fno-PIE -fno-stack-protector -L/home/ian/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/base-4.9.1.0 -Wl,-R,/home/ian/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/base-4.9.1.0 -L/home/ian/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1 -Wl,-R,/home/ian/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/integer-gmp-1.0.0.1 -lgmp -L/home/ian/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0 -Wl,-R,/home/ian/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0 -L/home/ian/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/rts -Wl,-R,/home/ian/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-nopie-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/rts -lm -lrt -ldl -lpthread
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using arch linux?  Here's the new way to fix this: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/2a715639fe20b5dccb84f6a37ed54d650fdcf119/doc/faq.md#i-get-strange-ld-errors-about-recompiling-with--fpic

Old way to fix this is adding `ghc-build: tinfo6` to your `~/.stack/config.yaml`, but that requires downloading and installing ghc again.